# How can I install packages native Node.js into node_modules?

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I want in my project to use native Node.js `crypto` package. This package will be loaded by the browser, and therefore it must be installed in `node_modules`.

I can do this:

```
npm install crypto
```

But how do I know whether in this case it is installing a package that is [described in the documentation Node.js](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto) (not someone's private package)?

Comment: The crypto package described in the node docs comes with node. It does not need to be installed. It is a node.js package and is not designed to work with browsers so most likely you can't use it in browsers.

Comment: Note though that browsers have a crypto API that's different from the one in node.js: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `crypto` in the same application in which you are running this command `npm install crypto`, it will be available as in this way you are installing it locally for your current application.

To use in another application as well, you should run command `npm install -g crypto` & then it can be used anywhere in your system's directory.

For more details, https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally

Comment: `npm install crypto` install [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto), but this is the package that is native to node.js?

Comment: yes...try installing globally using `npm install -g crypto`

Answer (score 0):

When you run `npm install crypto`, there is only one '`crypto`'.  Someone can't just create their own package called 'crypto' when there already is one.